# A class inside of a class

Tags: java, python, oop

I'm currently working with OOP and I got a question, Can we create a class inside of a class? For example can a class called Humans be split into two parts (Females - Males)? and each class (Females - Males) can have their own states and behaviors.

Comment: Short answer - yes. For a longer answer, you'll have to elaborate a bit more on what exactly you're trying to achieve, and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that but it would be better if you make the Males and Females into different classes and just inherit from the Human class.

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self, height, weight):
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight

class Male(Human):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Human.__init__(self, height, weight)  # This will inherit every attribute of the parent class.
        self.name = name

class Female(Human):
    ...some more code
```